# Streaming on Node Js

Tags: node.js, file, server, stream, readfile

Learning Streams in node js. I'm wondering Why we use Stream in node js when we have file system in node js.

Answer is stream spread data into pieces. and send across the network.

for that we node js provided this--> 
        createReadStream(fileName).pipe(res);

My Working Node Js Streaming code.

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const fs = require('fs');

const fileName = './pika.mp4';

createServer( (req,res) => {

res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
});

createReadStream(fileName).pipe(res);

}).listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running - 3000'));
```

Output is perfect no problem,

Problem is If I don't use stream and use readFile or readFileSync
Still I'm getting same Output.

Code -->

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const fs = require('fs');

const fileName = './pika.mp4';

createServer( (req,res) => {

fs.readFile(fileName,(err,data) => {


res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
});

res.write(data);

});

}).listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running - 3000'));
```

I'm confused I don't use stream here still at video is streaming.

Comment: If the `./pika.mp4` file is 1GB: it's manipulation means load 1GB in memory, and you can have some trouble with this. But with streams you will keep the momory down cause you manage a portion at time... and also is way more easier.

Comment: yes yes now I get it.
Correct me.
Stream helps Server take file from OS in chunks. not as big file.

this will be helpful to serve multiple request.

 file will be delivered to client browser when chunks get merged to original file.

Comment: `this will be helpful to serve multiple request` it depends, in this particular case you will read the file for each request. Also i think (with HTTP request) you will still need to load the entire file before sending it. Streams are really strong with sockets: stream load a chunk that is piped into the socket that sends it. With a request you will still need to wait to the file to be loaded in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the video files from fs module.

Answer (score 0):

Both codes are correct and stream the content of the file to the network.
They behave exactly the same way for the client.

However, the second one loads the whole file into the memory before sending the data to the network.
You should favour the first approach as it simple "connects" an output stream from a file reader to the input stream of the network response.

Answer (score -1):

Streaming in Node.js typically refers to handling streaming data, like reading or writing large amounts of data in chunks rather than loading the entire content into memory at once. Node.js provides built-in modules for handling streams, which can be useful for tasks like reading and writing files, handling HTTP requests and responses, and more.

Here's a basic example of how you might use streams to read a file and write its content to the console:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = 'example.txt';

// Create a readable stream to read the file
const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, 'utf8');

// Set up event handlers for the stream
readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('Received a chunk of data:');
  console.log(chunk);
});

readableStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('End of stream');
});

readableStream.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('An error occurred:', error);
});
```

In this example, a readable stream is created using `fs.createReadStream()`. The 'data' event is emitted whenever a chunk of data is available. The 'end' event is emitted when the entire file has been read, and the 'error' event is emitted if an error occurs during reading.

If you want to create a writable stream to write data to a file or other destinations, you can use `fs.createWriteStream()` or other relevant modules (e.g., for HTTP responses).

Remember that Node.js streams can also be piped together. For example, you can read data from one stream and write it to another, which is extremely useful for tasks like copying files or processing data without loading everything into memory.

Thanks